# Refresh JQuery UI Multiselect Widget

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm actualilly trying tu use this nice widget : http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/

I have two of this Widget in the same page, and what i'm trying to do is refreshing the second one when i select or deselect item in the first one.

For exemple, at the beggining, i only have this :

```
<select id="crc" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">

</select>
```

Then, on select and deselect event, I'm creating some more nodes and add them to this (and it works, it create something like this :

```
    <select id="crc" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option>test1</option>
        <option>test2</option>
    </select>
```

The problem is that I'm not able to refresh the second widget after adding the new options.
I fount an usefull post with similar problem and tried this :

```
$("#crc").multiselect("destroy").multiselect();
```

But it didn't work, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem.  Here's what worked for me:

To fix problem with destructor of ui.multiselect make the following change inside of the destroy function:

```
destroy: function() {
    this.element.show();
    this.container.remove();

    if ($.Widget === undefined)
        $.widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    else {
        $.Widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
        return this;
    }
}
```

The old version was:

```
destroy: function() {
    this.element.show();
    this.container.remove(); 
    $.widget.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

The reason of such changes is a new  $.Widget introduced in jQuery 1.8.  I also made the following changes/additions so that it would be compatible with IE9 and also provides a function to get selectedTexts as well.

```
// get all selected values in an array
selectedValues: function() {
    return $.map( this.element.find('option[selected]=selected'), function(item,i) { return $(item).val(); });
},
selectedTexts: function () {
    return $.map(this.element.find('option[selected]=selected'), function (item, i) { return $(item).html(); });
}
```